# How to break part of code using label and break statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make some part of my code stop looping, but keep looping for another variable. How can I possibly do that ? I tried this code but it's not working

```
// Looping based on number of data
for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {

    // Looping HTML table data output
    if ( !search || data[i].some(someSearch) ) {

        // Output table HTML + indexing number
        outputTable: {
            output += '<tr>';
            output += '<td>' + index + '</td>';

            for ( var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++ ) {
                output += '<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>';
            }

            output += '</tr>';

            index++;
        }

        // Data display limitation
        // based on combobox value
        if ( index > parseInt(searchLimit.val()) ) {
            break outputTable;
        }
    }

    // Count filtered data
    searchFiltered++;
}
```

From that code, I want to break the part of code inside `outputTable` label, but keep `searchFiltered` looping. Can someone help me? Thanks :)

Comment: You mean, you want to break the loop inside `outputTable`?

Comment: if is a conditional statement not a loop, there is a loop in the if condition `some` .

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Yes sir I want to stop `outputTable` when `index > parseInt(searchLimit.val())` statement is `true`.

Comment: Then shouldn't the if statement be inside the outputTable loop? With the break line being just `break;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `break` statement here. Put if condition like this. Every time the `index` value check it is lesser than `parseInt(searchLimit.val())`. if it is not it exit the if statement.

```
if ( index < parseInt(searchLimit.val()) ) {

 outputTable: {
            output += '<tr>';
            output += '<td>' + index + '</td>';

            for ( var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++ ) {
                output += '<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>';
            }

            output += '</tr>';

            index++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh I did not realized that ! Thanks sir.